# Given a general solution of a homogeneous system, find the general solution for nonhomogeneous system.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

> Given the general solution to the corresponding homogeneous system is $\Psi(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
> \mathit{e}^{-3t} &\mathit{e}^{-t} \\ 
> -\mathit{e}^{-3t} &\mathit{e}^{-t} 
> \end{bmatrix}C$, find the general solution of the system $x'=\begin{bmatrix}
> -2 &1 \\ 
> -1 &-2 
> \end{bmatrix}x+\begin{bmatrix}
> 2\mathit{e}^{-t}\\ 
> 3t
> \end{bmatrix}$, where $C$ is a nonsingular constant matrix.

Do I first try to find the system that $\Psi$ satisfies or do I solve the nonhomogeneous system? I am not sure what the first step is. I even tried to introduce $\Psi$ into the nonhomogeneous system to see if I can determine $C$, but I don't think this is the right direction.

Comment: It seems okay to assume that $\Psi$ is a solution the homogeneous system *corresponding* to the system given.

Comment: I see. Do I use the structure theorem, where the general solution is then $\Psi(t,\tau)\mathbf{\xi}+\int_{\tau}^{t}\Psi(t,\eta)g(\eta)d\eta$?

Comment: Interesting, because I just copied from the homework I was given!

Comment: If I change the $1$ to $-1$, then would $\Psi=\begin{bmatrix}
-\mathit{e}^{-t} &\mathit{e}^{-3t} \\ 
 \mathit{e}^{-t}& \mathit{e}^{-3t}
\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: May I ask why we need to use eigenvalues for this question?